# Link Button Click on Master Page causing Content Page Validators to Fire

Tags: c#, asp.net

In my ASP.Net page, i have a few link button controls which are placed in the master page. Whenever i click on the link button , the required field validators which are part of content page gets fired.

I don't want the validators to fire when someone clicks on the Link Buttons which are part of master page. Is there any way i can set the Page.ClientValidate() to true through javascript ??

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's a CausesValidation property which you can set to false for such controls.

You may also run into a situation where you wan't to keep validation groups seperate, then there's a ValidationGroup property for that. Only controls within the same validation group triggers validation in such cases. By default, all controls belong to the validation group without a name (empty string), that's why you're experiencing this problem.