# Sign In button on Master Page does not postback since a Form with validators stops a postback

Tags: asp.net

I have a MasterPage sectioned into a `<div>` tag for a Logo, Banner and a ASCX LogIn control, with the rest of the page in a `<div>` having the `<asp:ContentPlaceHolder>` to host all my ASPX pages. The Login control is in an Update panel.

---

**Problem :** 
Some of the ASPX pages have an ASCX page with a input form with text boxes with Custom Validators. When I click on the LogIn button, the resulting postback also tries to post this input data and fails since the forms are blank with no data....and thus the `postback` for the LogIn too does not go through. On other ASPX pages with no validations, the LogIn goes through.

I could solve this by having a separate page for Login...maybe with a ModalPopup etc ? But isn't there any other way to tackle 2 buttons on the same page....one of which comes from the Master ?

Comment: It sounds a little complex, yes. Also look into using ValidationGroups http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms227424%28v=vs.100%29.aspx and reading through http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178329%28v=vs.100%29.aspx

Comment: This set me thinking...in the right direction. And I also pruned my post to make it atleast "read" less complex.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you aren't validating the controls in the login form, just use CausesValidation="false" on the login button. If you are validating the login form, use Validation Groups as recommended by MikeSmithDev to control which controls are validated on submit. Creating a Validation Group for just the login controls should segregate them from the other controls on the page.

Comment: Yup. This works !  There is an earlier post, identical to my question <http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5938795/link-button-click-on-master-page-causing-content-page-validators-to-fire?rq=1>, with the right answer.